# knockout Text binding to display in single tag

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This is how my view looks

```
<div data-bind="foreach: RoleTypes">
            <h3 data-bind="text: RoleName"></h3>
        </div>
```

this is how the above code displays:

Teachers

Students

I would also like to `text: UserCount` to my  tag  so that my overall view would be:

Teachers (2)
Students (45)

How can i data-bind two text items into one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be do to:

```
<h3><!--ko text: RoleName--><!--/ko--> (<!--ko text: UserCount--><!--/ko-->)</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<h3><span data-bind="text:RoleName"></span> (<span data-bind="text:UserCount"></span>)</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find another post that it's answer was helpful: [Data-bind text inside another data-bind text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010621/data-bind-text-inside-another-data-bind-text) but i still want to know how i can add `( )` to surround the usercount.